# View JWT Token on jwt.io

Tags: jwt

I came across the badge section on jwt.io and the ['View on jwt.io'](http://jwt.io/assets/badge.svg) caught my eye. Is there a way to link to jwt.io, which then shows the users JWT token (from my application) and my verification key?

Skimming through the code of their page I couldn't find a clue on how to do that. Did I miss something on their page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm still trying to find the answer on how to preload the secret with my own, to help users see what was happening.

However I did manage to get the link to work correctly though:
[https://jwt.io/#id_token=your-token-here](https://jwt.io/#id_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ)

Found it on their blog post:
https://auth0.com/blog/2015/07/21/jwt-json-webtoken-logo/
Not sure how you were supposed to find it before they linked that post on [jwt.io](https://jwt.io).

Also linking this here, because I only just found it. I had been trying to find a nicely formatted documentation for our users for ages (before we just linked them to [jwt.io](https://jwt.io)):
https://auth0.com/learn/json-web-tokens/

Comment: That looks like a very good start! Do you also have an idea on how to pass the public key for verification in the case of RS256 algorithm?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I've had no success with loading anything into the signature block.

Comment: Me neither, thats unfortunate. But at least the most important part is possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I know it is many years later, but I have found how to pre-load the keys information (which I could find by using the "Share JWT" option, which actually creates a link).
The jwt.io debugger accepts additional query parameters:

- token - the JWT token value
- publicKey - as the name implies

Probably it does accept private key parameter, if given, and properly URL encoded, but did not test it. The example below uses a JWK form for the public key, but PKCS#8 and PKCS#1 are also accepted.

[Example](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImtleS1pZCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJjYTZmZTNmOS1lM2I2LTQ1YmEtOTU0Zi1lMjBiM2NmYTdmZDIiLCJpc3MiOiI2MmRlOWI5ZC1kNWUzLTQ4YWYtYmRhYi1lZmI3M2ZlOGUxMzAiLCJhdWQiOiJhdXRlbnRpLmNvbSIsImV4cCI6MTMwMDgxOTM4MCwiaWF0IjoxMzAwODE5MjgwfQ.KJiziG8bswLhtS6vvZ2ebzYPumtz-dMvhqQawXG2avmINZs80_j4utKqEkgtlZqrNNzWG8HCgdwrr0zco2tt4SX8nGXAsF0ztxh9ZnygYNo228N1GkRC-sO8OG9lp0XysQSgeDT-6rRCfkWOfb-VnVSsYz4GBSGtfkLKvWbbVl-Vv57Im6EXiscXbIWTn9La3bpuUy6lHU_PIg2jnhjcwuDG4oWHclCH77Fx-UdqmQaV-VPSgwPRtugqyl1O0QDwQjv41Vuo3XaHTx4IppyYq-0GJ6-M1xPIM4zlIrhesSq_GG3IOf-ob57Czks2K0tAuK5Ful0sELlZGcigzcOKsg&publicKey=%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22p%22%3A%20%220XwcXyU0Qp0ZtA9pQ_MG_AkUPxIWPq71rgcQFMivpF4ANrv_3H130o8GbAVn8BgicooLSVxeqUqd4Su2lousvHq13ieWcfINZOIv5pFKxPMFDB81rTr1Th2rFNFr1pUTZ6CdFtt1K5beYiuemWn_1jn8xUE7D8KxP6JpuzDoTVs%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22kty%22%3A%20%22RSA%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22q%22%3A%20%22yyL6yjIWawHy7ce8bs9-b4AaWI1d-dhdCW8JM5mulBdlQdEZNw4wCWhUFsq7HkljwzJWIfu_Ctne66aVvwwgKY5I5PHcDYwvyjbJXVScFgqdUJeD2nuA2nJvPk7DsTIN5z9GzBrgalMHJFXLoX76FuAZYzS-Oe05HGVQom4CZAE%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22d%22%3A%20%22iPt1YvA4I71TKE1_Ed-LCKPJROGXB5ejwTqh0fD_1HvfZQskCuVlAbuHIY0AeXev1ndXEeg4uJ8NZgFOUah3Yiu5XHXMhgZLFPny2K6Jbh0f944004xD-gm-1EfnuMbpfkmCz3DrUlNRKwviu2Ui9A7grwTN9A5T-prxT6ZdYZKAsP6zGU-cuneZy_U6aGym-HAnYkW9ennQlgNj11UMXi68TWcOHdRmBSMxBv98XpyNObCTOewNRxgkPPY3myy-V6LRhLq6IL_WXXd-A6o8FYR6la2klSvtL5YC_jpl280lGwDAxkQZP99tMhHSKIS6ZQhnQfXHRE2hzXxfDbKYAQ%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22e%22%3A%20%22AQAB%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22use%22%3A%20%22sig%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22kid%22%3A%20%22key-id%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22qi%22%3A%20%22TH6ylD_TDGAUxWYY9vWbiwT553PL3J5BzqK_QlyTQMBE4BWAnIGlwHualkUvqaBA7yWovl_OAzZdlV49-fsESKhid2Feo3W9OnDJy043Cpm_u4b7kYkzOldS9Tq3V57ikJdbfnuyZofrXWU6dm3Zuhz6T5A2NiGNreuX9RbMSJ0%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22dp%22%3A%20%22K01XZAeBvP9Sb9j7rnMPD4wk5kCr3ns2B6ooFdPCEtzneGj2I7K_0QOFlVCswoGKpViJqrlwS9hDuGbb0FTA-Rj4fRp7y8P4JtFmi2efKAUAFxhgdRWJ3YLeeWgsvWeFYldeAXqNxtvhzjMsDpRNsQ-9g1zPg5uAHiJJbstWSZ8%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22alg%22%3A%20%22RS256%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22dq%22%3A%20%22rRbiQZYKWiXv_MKcAoPVhWbPjDLxJ6pAJICzg39pLZD92-YzKSFytyFpvX4DkVwRoMrsb8qWT8Wz2HI62O6ZHS-7VzHrQrP4KMMkM92bnoBu6bQhSvK_qeOmfJ4ay4sOI8RcLCCeppqW1FQyzipnKUTM_SZ9DNjhOBvwaGd6rAE%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22n%22%3A%20%22pjoKM9_DRPFOHFvI6q_COkAkmND2mx57DF5rNwNXOHopdiQFR9pYDtRj45kI_BmCEKck5ff2tp31xpwhvqpzTUYoCTX4k3z4HRv4fDKnTRTybqeCJgLyM_NRzOyDayJ1DvDetvBsPfABIT9cNzs4VSQvVZvnEi4CATfEZoSWEna7amkawDya3qYwmMIBdCrLozrGB92Gujz6jWCdwKrnpmZ5LqhJmfRRF7ETcdWlnEN2olK4Q7wcNAXbkFKQyOeuyAJAZwof33Ca-_kRhBhenj8gy2lmR5252abNFLFVm_sS5Mpx_HU85Nn_bHuObY6b-6T-X_513Fz3fh95o9XZWw%22%0A%7D)